# Get the Date into parameters as integers

Tags: java, calendar

How can I get the day_of_month, month and the year into parameters as integers?

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar start_date = Calendar.getInstance();     
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(start_date.getTime()));

int day = start_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = start_date.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = start_date.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String result = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

but, the date today is: 01/12/12, while the result is: 01/11/12.

Comment: MONTH is 0-11, see the javadoc of `Date`

Comment: The Java tag already says that the question belongs to Java language.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. Month goes from 0 to 11. You can check this by issuing:

```
System.out.println(Calendar.JANUARY);
```

- [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)
- [Calendar.MONTH in particular](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)

By the way, to convert dates to Strings, you should really use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").format(start_date.getTime());
```

(sidenote, but important: **SimpleDateFormat is not thread safe** very much not thread safe, so don't try to optimize by using them as static instances in a multithreaded environment! This is also stated in the API doc: `Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.`)

Comment: At least set a link to the official `Calendar` documentation.

Answer (score 1):

month index starts from 0, thats why gives 11

> 0- january
>   .
>   .
>   .
>   11-december

Answer (score 1):

In `Calendar` class Month starts with 0 which is January and ends with 11 which is December.

[Open JDk 6](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.0JANUARY)-

```
public final static int JANUARY = 0;
...
public final static int DECEMBER = 11;
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `MONTH` (the emphasis is mine):

> `MONTH`: Field number for get and set indicating the month. This is a calendar-specific value. The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY **which is 0**; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

Human calendars start January at one, not at zero. That is why December ends up at eleven instead of twelve.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use java.util.Date and other bad parts of java

From Java 8 joda time will be in standard library so I do not see point in using bad code.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

You will not have issues with this one, trust me.

Comment: It won't be Joda Time - it'll be JSR-310, which is somewhat different. There are still issues in terms of the Joda Time API too, but I agree it's *much* better than Calendar/Date.

Comment: License will be different, thats for sure but point is to switch now if you can.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the license - I was talking about the API. It's *not* just moving Joda Time to a different package.

Comment: Your right, thanks for update. Still I guess its fair to say that we both agree that Alon Shmiel should use better library

Comment: Its not an argument to switch to another lib , only because somebody uses the existing lib in a wrong way. Better not trust you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, the result of `start_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)` is a `int` ranging from 0 to 11, where 0 is January and 11 is December.

[Calendar.MONTH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MONTH)